# Is this URL format an .ASPX convention?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am looking at a web-app, that has a set-up page(i.e, on the actual web-app) with the following URL shown in the form(i.e, we can change it to something else):

```
http://www.mart.com/cpp/public_panelpage_earlyScreenOut.asp?supplier=fed&code=[%PID%][%SUPPLIER_ENCRYPT_URL%]
```

So I believe that the [%XYZ%] represents an argument that will be filled in dynamically? thanks!

Comment: Yes, `[%XYZ%]` looks like it will be replaced with an actual argument. There's nothing I see here though that I would call an ASPX convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this URL format an .ASPX convention?

It is not a convention.

> So I believe that the [%XYZ%] represents an argument that will be filled in dynamically?

The usage of `[% ... %]` appear to be tokenizers used by a, server-side, parsing engine.

*Note - when working with URL's the `%` sign along the `&` and `?` are special characters and should be encoded properly if you intend to pass them through the URL.*

Comment: I see, so it's not a standard, but something like REGEX?

Comment: No, it is just a token to tell a parsing engine it should be replaced with meaningful data.